# Creating template specializations via a macro

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a helper method `createTypedArray` that "knows" how many bytes per element to allocate. That is, `createTypedArray<Float32Array>(size)` and not `createTypedArray<Float32Array, 4>(size)`.

This is the best approach I've come up with. Is there a better approach? There's a dummy primary template that I don't love, at least.

```
#define TYPED_ARRAY_P(T, bytesPerElement)                                            \
  template <>                                                                        \
  Local<T> createTypedArray<T>(size_t size) {                                        \
    size_t byteLength = size * bytesPerElement;                                      \
    Local<ArrayBuffer> buffer = ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), byteLength); \
    Local<T> result = T::New(buffer, 0, size);                                       \
    return result;                                                                   \
  }

// Dummy
template <typename T>
Local<T> createTypedArray(size_t s) {
  return void;
}

TYPED_ARRAY_P(Uint8Array, 1);
TYPED_ARRAY_P(Uint16Array, 2);
TYPED_ARRAY_P(Uint32Array, 4);

#undef TYPED_ARRAY_P
```

Comment: Er, why don't you just use `sizeof(T)`?

Comment: @GManNickG unfortunately it's 1 for all types. (Float32Array & friends are from v8 -- I can't control that.)

Comment: Yikes, these are some poorly designed classes. There don't even seem to be any typedefs or constant or functions or anything for getting the size of an element. I would suggest making something like `template <typename T> struct V8ArrayToElementSize;` and specialize this for each array type, like `template <> struct V8ArrayToElementSize<Uint8Array> { static constexpr value = 1; };`. Then you can have your one function, and replace `bytesPerElement` with `V8ArrayToElementSize<T>::value`.

Comment: @GManNickG thanks. If you want to post that as an answer I'd accept it. Otherwise I'll probably answer my own question showing that fully implemented.

Comment: Sure, I forget that I can do that sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd like to use `sizeof(ElementType)`, such as:

```
auto buffer = AllocateSomeBuffer(numberOfElements * sizeof(ElementType));
```

You're not working with `ElementType` directly, though, but instead some representation of an array type. No worries, we just need to get `ElementType` out of your `T`.

Sadly, these classes don't appear to have something like `T::value_type` or `T::element_size` or anything really. However, we'd still really like to have a "guaranteed" mapping between a `T` and its element size, and not pull out some magic constants each time.

The usual solution to problems like these are "type traits". These are class specializations that give us some computed information about a type. In our case, we want something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct V8TypeTraits;  // no generic case (e.g. can't ask for V8 traits about int)

template <>
struct V8TypeTraits<Uint8Array> {
    typedef std::uint8_t value_type;
};

// etc.
```

Now we can get `ElementType`:

```
template <typename T>
Local<T> createTypedArray(size_t elementCount) {
    const size_t byteLength =
        elementCount * sizeof(typename V8TypeTraits<T>::value_type);
    // etc.
    return result;
}
```

Obviously you don't have to do `value_type`, you could instead put `static constexpr element_size = /* whatever */;` in your traits and use:

```
const size_t byteLength =
        elementCount * V8TypeTraits<T>::element_size;
```

But mapping to `value_type` is the shortest path back into C++ land (e.g., it would be redundant to have both `value_type` and `element_size`, and the former is more generic, so I pick that one).

Comment: MSVC compiles without complaint, but with GCC I had to write `sizeof(typename V8TypeTraits<T>::value_type)`. (Not sure if this is because I'm using `float` and not `std::float_t`, but I don't want `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to affect these typedefs.) Thanks again.

Comment: @ZachB: Whoops, my mistake. GCC is correct here. My original draft example used `element_size` which is a value and does not need `typename`. But when a type depends on a template expansion, you must tell the compiler that the result of this will be a type using `typename`. MSVC is non-compliant in this regard. Good catch.